# Run Queries Unrelated to Controller in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-model

I have a Controller for Jobs with a model Job.

When I hit /jobs  (the index function of Job Controller), I need to run a query on 2 other tables (not joined to Job) to find values to manually insert into jobs before actually displaying the index.

I have tried several things but can't seem to make any progress on this.

Can anyone help me with this?

1) select fields from a join on customers and packages (complex conditions)
2) iterate through results and insert/update values in job
3) display jobs

Thank you in advance.

Manikandan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may work as well if placed under beforeFilter in AppController:

```
if($this->referer() == '/users/login' && $this->Auth->user()){
    $this->loadModel('User');
    $this->User->id = $this->Auth->User('id');
    $this->User->saveField('last_login', date(DATE_ATOM));
}
```

Comment: What does line 3 means? Can someone post a reference to the CakePHP page that explains this feature? `$this->User->id = ...`

Answer (score 5):

You can load non-related models [in a number of ways](http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/msg/794c451038c0c798), but this is probably the best one for controllers:

```
$this->loadModel('Customer');
$customers = $this->Customer->find('all');
```

---

Alternatives include:

```
ClassRegistry::init('Customer')->find('all');
// or (equivalent)
$customer = ClassRegistry::init('Customer')
$customers = $customer->find('all');
```

or:

```
App::import('Model', 'Customer');
$customer = new Customer();
$customers = $customer->find('all');
```

Comment: I'm assuming that Customer and Package are related here, and you don't need to create an on-the-fly relationship from Job to either of these models.